# Scroll To First Element That Begins with Character with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a pretty long list of names and I wanted to build a quick simple navigation to scroll to the names that begin with a certain character.

So, if I had links like -

```
<a href="a">A</a>
<a href="b">B</a>
<a href="c">C</a>
```

I would normally have anchors or divs with ids set up between the characters, and scroll to them.  In this case, I don't have anchors or divs before each new beginning letter, I just have a long list.

Say each name in the list is in a `<h1 class="name">Someone's Name</h1>`

I can get the letter with

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var letter = $(this).attr('href');
    //scroll to first h1.name element that begins with "letter"
 });
```

so once I have that letter, is there a way I can find the first element that is a `h1.name` that begins with that letter with JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and check the text inside the `h1` element against the value of `letter`(whether the text starts with the given text)

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var letter = $(this).attr('href');
    //scroll to first h1.name element that begins with "letter"
    var $target = $('h1.name').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase().indexOf(letter) == 0
    });
    //scroll to $target
});
```

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) was not used since it will search for the given text in any position not just the start.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, as `target` is returning undefined - http://jsfiddle.net/Tb8Ap/1/ - please advise.  thanks

Comment: @RCNeil see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Tb8Ap/5/ - the letter is in lower case but the text is in upper case

Comment: ah, perfect.  it was just `toLowerCase()`.  Can you please update your answer and I will mark accepted?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can prime a cache that contains the elements for each letter:

```
var letters = {};

$('h1.name').each(function() {
    // find first letter of element contents
    var letter = (this.textContent || this.innerText || '').toLowerCase()[0];

    if (letter && !(letter in letters)) {
        letters[letter] = this; // add to cache
    }
});
```

And then use that inside the click handler to scroll the corresponding element into view:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // use last letter of anchor
    var letter = this.getAttribute('href').toLowerCase();

    if (letter in letters) {
        letters[letter].scrollIntoView();
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb8Ap/2/)

Comment: @RCNeil I've made a few tweaks; see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb8Ap/2/).

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this.  Greatly appreciated, and great to see there's multiple methods.